# getting divs side by side horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my pictures and descriptions divs to line up in a straight line horizontally. There are 3 different divs that I would like to be side by side horizontally. It will not allow me when I use float: left. I have tried for days and it is still not working.  I would appreciate if someone could help me figure this out. There are images before each description but will now show up in the preview below. 
Here is my code below:

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#1 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#2 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#3 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Content">
  <div id="1">
    <p><img src="http://beerhold.it/300/300" height="300px" width="300px" alt="Project 1"></p>
    <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <center>
      <p><img src="http://beerhold.it/300/300" height="300px" width="300px" alt="Project 2"></p>
    </center>
    <center>
      <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <p><img src="http://beerhold.it/300/300" height="300px" width="300px" alt="Project 3"></p>
    <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: have a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but your problems seems to be you have a div that is the same size as the image, but you also have text in the div.  Also your content container - if you get the case correct for the id is only 100px wide when each div is 300px - how do you expect them to fit on the same line?

Comment: You can also make your divs inside the #content div have display:inline-block;
#content > div { display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 2):

you have a few mistakes in your code

- your container is only 100px wide, make it larger.
- If you have the same properties applied, use a class instead to not repeat yourself in CSS
- Don't use `width/height` HTML attributes, use CSS attributes instead
- CSS is case-sensative. so careful with `#Content`  and `#content`
- don't use `center` html , it is deprecated.

use flexbox, so you can achieve a responsive layout easily

```css
#content {
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  border: red solid;
}

.divs {
  padding: 25px
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="divs" id="1">
    <p><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" alt="Project 1"></p>
    <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="divs" id="2">
    <p><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" alt="Project 2"></p>
    <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="divs" id="3">
    <p><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" alt="Project 3"></p>
    <p>Description, Description, Description</p>
  </div>


</div>
```